# Getting Runtime Assemblies in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, assemblies

I am currently writing a framework dll which has an AssemblyHelper.
This helper stores Runtime and UserAdded assemblies to easily instantiate new objects.

The .NET part of the framework uses:

```
AppDomain MyDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
Assembly[] AssembliesLoaded = MyDomain.GetAssemblies();
_runtimeAssemblies = AssembliesLoaded;
```

This gets me all the assemblies I need.

But the problem is I can't use this with Silverlight and I have no idea what to use now.
Currently I am using:

```
Assembly[] AssembliesLoaded = {Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()};
```

But this only adds the Assembly of my framework and not the one of the application or any other runtime assembly.

What should I use? please help!

Thanks in advance,

Wouter

Comment: Alright I think this just isn't possible.

I am now trying to write some code that looks in the same folder for other dll and exe's to fetch assemblies from. I know Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() won't work so I am still looking for some solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `System.Windows.Deployment` class is the closest you are going to get to the list of assemblies in the application.

The `Deployment.Current.Parts` collection is a list the `AssemblyPart` object that specify the name and source uri of the individual dlls packaged in the Xap.

I'm not sure that is much of a help to you though.