# Json.NET fails to serialize dictionary of sets

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary, set, json.net

I'm trying to serialize (and later on deserialize) a `Dictionary<string, ISet<string>>`. Unfortunately, Json.NET (v6.0.3 via NuGet) fails to do this. What I do is

```
var value = new Dictionary<string, ISet<string>>
    {
        {"foo", new HashSet<string>{"bar"}}
    };
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
    };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, settings);
```

The variable `json` then holds the string

```
{"$type":"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], System]], mscorlib","foo":["bar"]}
```

Now I want to deserialize the string with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, ISet<string>>>(json, settings);
```

which fails in resolving the Dictionary type, because it cannot find the `System` assembly that `ISet` belongs to. When I instead do the following

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, ISet<string>>>(json);
```

everything works just fine. So it appears that the `TypeNameHandling` setting (changing/omitting the format does not change anything) actually breaks deserialization.

I found that, if I don't set the `TypeNameHandling` settings, the serialized `$type` properties are simply ignored. I.e., when deserializing, the type information is taken solely from the target type where they are resolved. This works.

When setting the `TypeNameHandling`, type resolution happens via reflection within the Json.NET assembly, which does not have a dependency on the `System` assembly and therefore fails to resolve the `ISet` interface. I can fix this by registering on `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` and resolving the assembly like so

```
if (args.Name == "System")
{
     return typeof (ISet<>).Assembly;
}
```

but this seems very fragile to me, as it solves the problem for only this one specific assembly and I have to add another case for every assembly I need somewhere.

Does anyone have experience on how to solve this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ISet<T> resides in System.dll. And your example works fine for me in same version of json.NET and .NET 4.5.

Comment: Interesting, I'm on .Net 4.0, but I don't think that's the problem... I'll dig into it.

Comment: I found the cause of the error in passing the settings into the deserialization. I updated my question accordingly. Though the immediate problem is resolved, it would really interest me, why passing along the settings causes this error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar problem was addressed in the following thread: [How can I deserialize with TypeNameHandling.Objects in Json.NET Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860565/how-can-i-deserialize-with-typenamehandling-objects-in-json-net-silverlight)

The problem seems to be that Json is failing to load the assembly with partial name. You could overcome this issue by using `TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full`.

Comment: Sorry for my earlier comment, this indeed solves the issue. Although I don't exactly understand why... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the source code for NewtonSoft.Json in DefaultSerializationBinder.GetTypeNameFromTypeNameKey approx. row 83.. It tries to get the type

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], System]]

from assembly

mscorlib.dll

```
Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
```

Which returns null. This is with FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple.

If you use FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full then the same type will be:

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

And then:

```
Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
```

Will work and hence the deserialization works as well.

I cant say why this is the case though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, helped me a lot. +1 for that. I accept Edin's reply though, since he proposed the same solution earlier. Nevertheless, thank you very much!