# Hangfire looking for ISet in mscorlib.dll

Tags: hangfire, mscorlib

I'm getting this runtime exception with Hangfire after upgrading to .NET6

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0
at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.TypeResolver(Assembly assembly, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase)    
at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.DefaultTypeResolver(String typeName)    
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()    
at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
```

ISet isn't in mscorlib.dll from what I can tell. It's supposed to be in System.Runtime.dll according to the docs.

Any ideas why Hangfire is doing this? I'm using Hangfire.AspNetCore 1.7.27.

Comment: I think you should look in you hangfire database for an old recurring or scheduled job taking an `ISet` as parameter, or having a parameter with a property (or sub* property) being an `ISet`

Comment: Oh wow, I had been so focussed on thinking it was some sort of package/dll issue I had not considered looking into the database. I was using an in memory db but switching to a file-based one I can indeed see that we are inserting jobs with ISet params. Thanks so much for the hint, I'll see if I can figure out what to do with this now and will post back

Comment: Why is ISet a problem now, out of interest?

Comment: This does seem to work by the way! I changed the parameter we were storing from a set to a simple string array and I'm getting past the error, thanks. If you post as an answer I'll mark it as accepted, cheers. Bonus points if you can mention why ISet is no longer valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you should look in your Hangfire database for a serialized parameter featuring a `ISet`.
It is the deserialization of this parameter which causes the issue, as indicated by :

```
at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
```

As to the root cause of the problem, I was first thinking that the job had been enqueued with an older version of the framework, while the dequeue attempt was with a newer version of the framework. But this might also be a serialization settings issue, as stated by [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23652267/1236044)