# Use reflection to iterate types in all referenced assemblies, in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, reflection

Is there an equivilent to this in silverlight?

```
 var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=VS.95).aspx

Is there another way of doing this?

Here's a post on how to do it for design time under blend... but how at runtime?

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/the-ultimate-hack-for-silverlight-in-blend/

---

Doesn't look like this is possible:

[Getting Runtime Assemblies in Silverlight 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637549/getting-runtime-assemblies-in-silverlight-3?answertab=active#tab-top)

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/22050/77847.aspx

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/22050.aspx/1?Get+a+list+of+loaded+assemblies

Comment: Why doesnt this work in Silverlight? And what is it you are eventually trying to achieve.

Comment: I can't find `GetAvailableTypes()`. Do you mean `GetExportedTypes()` or `GetTypes()`?

Comment: GetTypes is what I know from bog-standard .NET

Comment: That edit an hour ago changed the meaning of the question. Please don't do such edits. Instead ask a new question with the new problem.

Comment: @Anders Abel: If this is preferable to the community, no problem.  The question as it now is, better reflects what I was driving at though.  Hope that's okay.

Comment: For me it's fine for now, I've updated my answer (which is still the only one, so it's should be ok with this question). When there are many answers that answer the different versions of the question things get very confusing. It is also frustrating to spend time writing an answer, just to find out an hour later that the question changed making the answer completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The question originally asked for something equivalent to `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetAvailableTypes()` in Silverlight, so that's my first answer.*

Silverlight supports reflection:

- `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` is supported in Silverlight, including Windows Phone 7 and XBox 360.
- `Assembly.GetExportedTypes()` and `Assembly.GetTypes()` are both supported in Silverlight, including Windows 7 and XBox 360.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=VS.95).aspx) and select "Silverlight" as the version for details.

#### Update

- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` is supported in Silverlight 3 and 4.
- `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` is supported in Silverlight 4.

The easiest is to upgrade to Silverlight 4 instead of having to do workarounds.

Comment: I confirm that the .GetAssemblies() method exists under System.AppDomain (in Silverlight mscorlib 2.0.5.0), but for some strange reason VS2010 is saying it cannot resolve the symbol.  See: http://forums.silverlight.net/p/202427/472798.aspx

Comment: Have you set the target to Silverlight 4? `GetAssemblies()` is not available if you have the target set to Silverlight 3.

Comment: just double checked.  The target is SL4.  For now I've statically linked all types into a List.  I might come back to this in SL5, *or* consider decompiling Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.Harness.ReflectionUtility.GetAssemblies.  I will test around a little more on empty SL projects and see what happens.  ty.

Comment: I looked at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' and the GetAssemblies overload is not there. This would be in line with it being a SecurityCritical member on the Desktop CLR, so there's not much use for it in SL anyway. Could you please point us to MSDN or a similar resource? Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx SL is not listed under supported platforms.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not getting it to work in my SL4 project either, but I tried to cast the the current domain to a dynamic and it works, a dummy workaround until I get VS2010 to recognize that I' using the correct mscorlib.

Dummy workaround:

```
var loadedAssemblies = ((dynamic)Thread.GetDomain()).GetAssemblies()as Assembly[];
```

Comment: Interesting. It almost seems as if the compiler is refusing to generate code that calls this method directly, even though it's there. I'm not sure why Microsoft would want to do that though, especially if it's so easy to circumvent.

Comment: A reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll is required yo use this workaround.