# Is there an alternative to AppDomain.GetAssemblies on portable library?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I'm looking for a way to get the current app's assemblies inside a portable library project.

In classic library project, the code line below do the job:

```
var assemblies = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

But seems that System.AppDomain is not available to portable library.

Does anyone know a way to get the current domain assemblies on portable library?

Comment: You'll need to work with the fact that if a class or method isn't available in PCL then it is *very* unlikely that there is a portable alternative.  AppDomain isn't available in Silverlight and WinRT apps for example.  You forgot to mention the targets you want to support.  But clearly you can't wring water out of stone, if the target you want doesn't support it then you have a library that cannot work.

Comment: May I ask why you need to get the list of all assemblies in the current AppDomain from a PCL in the first place?

Comment: Can you provide more information? From the usage I've seen, pulling the current assemblies from the current AppDomain makes the assumption that all assemblies in a given application have already been loaded.

Comment: For Silverlight, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962981/use-reflection-to-iterate-types-in-all-referenced-assemblies-in-silverlight

Answer (score 6):

You can use platform hooks:

In your portable library:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PCL {
  public interface IAppDomain {
    IList<IAssembly> GetAssemblies();
  }

  public interface IAssembly {
    string GetName();
  }

  public class AppDomainWrapper {
    public static IAppDomain Instance { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and you can access them (in your portable library) like:

```
AppDomainWrapper.Instance.GetAssemblies();
```

In your platform-dependent application you'll need to implement it:

```
public class AppDomainWrapperInstance : IAppDomain {
  IList<IAssembly> GetAssemblies() {
    var result = new List<IAssembly>();
    foreach (var assembly in System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
      result.Add(new AssemblyWrapper(assembly));
    }
    return result;
  }
}

public class AssemblyWrapper : IAssembly {
  private Assembly m_Assembly;
  public AssemblyWrapper(Assembly assembly) {
    m_Assembly = assembly;
  }

  public string GetName() {
    return m_Assembly.GetName().ToString();
  }
}
```

and bootstrap it

```
AppDomainWrapper.Instance = new AppDomainWrapperInstance();
```