# How to list all loaded assemblies in PCL (portable class library)

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

It's easy to get list of all loaded assemblies in .NET:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

But I can't find a way to do this in PCL (portable class library) code? Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898871/is-there-an-alternative-to-appdomain-getassemblies-on-portable-library

Comment: AppDomain just isn't portable.  Entirely missing in Store and Phone8, very limited capabilities in the CoreCLR.  So it is omitted in PCL.

Comment: I know that AppDomain isn't portable. So there is no way to get all loaded assemblies in PCL?

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if *Deployment.Current.Parts* is available in PCL, but I use:

```
public static List<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
{
    List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

    foreach (var assemblyPart in Deployment.Current.Parts)
    {
        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(assemblyPart.Source, UriKind.Relative));
        Assembly a = new AssemblyPart().Load(sri.Stream);

        if (a != null)
            assemblies.Add(a);
    }

    return assemblies;   
}
```

Comment: Deployment it´s not available in PCL