# What is the equivalent of NETFX_CORE in the case of windows 8.1 portable class library project targeting multi-platform?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library, class-library, windows-8.1-universal

I have an existing class library project which is targeted to the Windows 8.1.

[image]

It uses the `Windows.Networking.Sockets` library when it is **Windows 8.1 App** otherwise uses the regular `System.Net.Sockets` via help of **NETFX_CORE**.

Detail using directive are below:

```
#if !NETFX_CORE
using System.Net.Sockets;
#else
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
#endif
```

Now i have tried to add an extra platform support of **Windows Phone 8.1** along with Windows 8.1, instead of Windows 8.1 only.

[image]

Seems `NETFX_CORE` is not sufficient now.

Could anyone tell me the equivalent of `NETFX_CORE` in this case which will identify **both the Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1**?

Comment: Are you doing this as a single PCL library, or are you sharing source amongst projects?

Comment: i am sharing the source as linked file.

Comment: You can also consider platform hooks approach instead (like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898871/is-there-an-alternative-to-appdomain-getassemblies-on-portable-library)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PCL.  What conditional symbols are defined is purely a project setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own symbol in the project settings, or better still, just build a single PCL version of the library that targets all your target platforms - you can then include this without needing to build a separate version for each platform, with all the pre-compiler directives.