# Is there an alternative to AppDomain.GetAssemblies on portable project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, portable-class-library

I trying to get the assemblies list. But I facing an exception in `portable` UWP project.

The following code works in

**`.netframework`**

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

**`Xamarin portable`**

```
var currentdomain = typeof(string).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetType("System.AppDomain").GetRuntimeProperty("CurrentDomain").GetMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
var getassemblies = currentdomain.GetType().GetRuntimeMethod("GetAssemblies", new Type[] { });
var assemblies = getassemblies.Invoke(currentdomain, new object[] { }) as Assembly[];
```

But the same above code is not working in the **`UWP portable`**. (I think the portable is working in the UWP too)

I am getting the following issue while hitting the first line

> 'typeof(string).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetType("System.AppDomain").GetRuntimeProperty("CurrentDomain").GetMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { })' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       HResult: -2146233079
>       HelpLink: null
>       InnerException: null
>       Message: "The API 'System.AppDomain.get_CurrentDomain()' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information."
>       Source: "mscorlib"
>       StackTrace: "   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)"

If I use the below code

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
Assembly[] assembly = ((dynamic)Thread.GetDomain()).GetAssemblies() as Assembly[];
var loadedAssemblies = ((dynamic)Thread.GetDomain()).GetAssemblies() as Assembly[];
```

then I get following error.

> The name 'AppDomain' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context

I checked the [Is there an alternative to AppDomain.GetAssemblies on portable library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898871/), But this is not helped to fix my issue.

Comment: PCL is officially dead. .NET Standard 2.0 already has the related API.

Comment: @LexLi How can I get it by .NET Standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, .NET Standard libraries are the replacement for Portable Class Libraries (PCL). See the [.NET Standard 2.0 Support in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/net-standard). You can use the following code to get all the assemblies in the package of the UWP app,

```
private async Task<List<Assembly>> GetAssemblyListAsync()
{
    var PackageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    foreach (StorageFile file in await PackageFolder.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        if (file.FileType == ".dll" || file.FileType == ".exe")
        {
            AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName() { Name = file.Name };
            Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(name);
            assemblies.Add(asm);
        }
    }
    return assemblies;
}
```

However, from .Net standard 2.0, you can use `AppDomain.GetAssemblies` directly in UWP app to get the assemblies.

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

You need to download [Visual Studio 2017 15.4](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) or above and set your app target version and min version Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (16299). Besides, you can also create a .Net Standard 2.0 class library to use the `AppDomain.GetAssemblies`.

[image]